# How to sort by word count and in alphabetical order?

Tags: php, sorting

How can I sort a set of phrases in an alphabetical order, but take into consideration the number of words too? I've tried `sort()`, `usort()` and `natsort()`, with no luck. Example:

```
Cube Pro Duo
Cube Pro
Cube Pro Trio
```

I would expect "Cube Pro" to come first as it has fewer words, but doesn't seem to work, whichever SORT I use?

Comment: 1. Please add your attempt into your question 2. Do you have this data in an array?

Comment: Natsort() produces:
 Array ( [1] => Cube Pro Duo~53 [2] => Cube Pro Trio~54 [0] => Cube Pro~52 )

Comment: But I am applying this to other phrases too. I am trying to get a consistent way to sort the array by 1.number of words on the string, then 2. alphabetically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

[`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is the way to go here. I first compare the amount of words, which I get by  counting the amout of spaces with [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php). If the  count of words are equal I simply do a [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) to compare both strings. If the amounts of words are different I simply compare them.

```
<?php

    $arr = ["Cube Pro Duo", "Cube Pro", "Cube Pro Trio"];

    usort($arr, function($a, $b){
        $countA = substr_count($a, " ")+1;
        $countB = substr_count($a, " ")+1;

        if($countA == $countB) {
            return strcasecmp($a, $b);
        } else {
            return $countA > $countB ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Cube Pro
    [1] => Cube Pro Duo
    [2] => Cube Pro Trio
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Saved the day. I've gone 'code blind'

Comment: For sorting multi-dimensional arrays you can use `array_multisort()` combined with with `array_map()`. Ex: `array_multisort(array_map(function($element) {
          return str_word_count($element['key']);
      }, $array), SORT_ASC, $array);`, where `key` is the key to target.